# Database insert query not working

Tags: 8, database

I have used the following code to insert values to database

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->insert('node__field_ssl_cert_fields');      
$query->fields([
  'entity_id',
  'revision_id',
    'delta',
    'field_ssl_cert_fields_privatekey',
    'field_ssl_cert_fields_csr'
]);
$query->values([
  $nid,0,0,$pkeyout,$csrout
]);
$query->execute();
```

When I printed the query it is as follows

```
INSERT INTO {node__field_ssl_cert_fields} (entity_id, revision_id, 
delta, field_ssl_cert_fields_privatekey, field_ssl_cert_fields_csr)
VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
:db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4)
```

Here `node__field_ssl_cert_fields` is the table. `entity_id, revision_id, delta, field_ssl_cert_fields_privatekey, field_ssl_cert_fields_csr` are fields.

What will be the fault?

Comment: It throws an error? Normally for a autoincrement column (in this case the entity_id) should be passed as NULL in MySql i think

Comment: No errors in error log

Comment: There should be definitely an error log, check first Drupal recent log messages, then apache/nginx error logs, then mysql / database error log. 

What displays the browser that it's went wrong?

Comment: Please define "insert query not working". My only suggestion is to try to use the Drupal 8 Entity API instead of inserting field values into field tables yourself.

Comment: Yes, you should never write data directly into a field table yourself. Load the entity, set the value, save. Maybe your only problem is that you still get the cached entity, which is one of the things that the API will take care of for you.